# Распараллелить алгоритм поиска в тексте на Cuda

Tags: cuda

Стоит задача распараллелить алгоритм поиска слова в текстовом файле. Пока не понимаю, как распределить текст равномерно между потоками. Возможно ли вообще использовать для этого cuda?

Comment: Мне интересно, удалось продвинуться? | Так-то можно найти варианты: [CUDA-text-search](https://github.com/n00rsy/CUDA-text-search)